# Is there any PostgreSQL driver for erlang that supports stored procedures?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, erlang

I am looking for a PostgreSQL driver for erlang that supports stored procedures? Would be great if it would support connection pooling as well.

Answer (score 6):

```
epgsql git://github.com/wg/epgsql
epgsql_pool git://github.com/burinov/epgsql_pool
```

Are good to go!